# spring data mongodb - insert a date plus some days using mongodb server time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In Oracle, we can use sysdate and do arithmetic on it while inserting date thereby not relying on the java application server time.

I know we can use the $currentDate update modifier through Update.currentDate in spring data but how do I add X days for example?

This question is about MongoDB and not Oracle. :-)

Comment: I don't think you can do it on insert. However in 4.2 update can accept aggregation pipeline so you might be able to use $dateAdd.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by **INTERVAL** statement but it works fine when you convert days with hours.

please build your query like this.

```
@Query(value = "select * from activation_codes a where a.type = :type and a.id_account = :id_account and a.creation_time <= NOW() - :hoursAgo * INTERVAL '1 hour'", nativeQuery = true)
List<ActivationCode> getAllAddedAtLeastXHoursAgo(@Param("id_account") int id_account, @Param("type") int type, @Param("hoursAgo") int hoursAgo);
```

This will help you in comparing the DateTime with x-days(convert days to time in hours).

Comment: Question about mongoDB not Oracle.